# getting nginx to serve static files (django, gunicorn)

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, ubuntu-18.04

When `DEBUG = True`, Django serves the static files and I can see my site, and the admin page, styled correctly and run the correct js. My intuition is I have misconfigured nginx, and I'm struggling to find the cause. Some background:

```
sudo nginx -t && sudo systemctl restart nginx
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

```
cat sites-enabled/mysite
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name IP_ADDR;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static {
        root /home/ubuntu/mysite;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

which is symlinked to `sites-available/mysite`

`/var/log/nginx/error.log` only has the line `2020/03/01 19:57:49 [notice] 20644#20644: signal process started`, but the access log has a number of 404s. Upon trying to access the application URL, chrome dev console shows:

```
Refused to apply style from 'IP_ADDR:8000/static/css/console.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
IP_ADDR/:9 GET IP_ADDR:8000/static/js/jquery.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
IP_ADDR/:11 GET IP_ADDR:8000/static/js/console.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
IP_ADDR/:10 GET IP_ADDR:8000/static/js/content.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
IP_ADDR/:11 GET IP_ADDR:8000/static/js/console.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
favicon.ico:1 GET IP_ADDR:8000/static/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)
```

I have `include /etc/nginx/mime.types;` in my nginx.conf, and `mime.types` includes the line

`text/html                             html htm shtml;`,

though I think that's correct since my css file should be `text/css`, but I don't know the best way to get over that hurdle. I've run `python manage.py collectstatic` and my project structure is this:

```
(venv) ubuntu@IP_ADDR:~/mysite$ tree -L 1
.
├── README.md
├── manage.py
├── mysite
├── requirements.txt
├── static
├── venv
└── mysite_views_urls_templates
```

I'm not sure if I've even given enough information, I'm really trying to deepen my understanding of the whole stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that I was running gunicorn manually over port 8000, blocking nginx from delivering the static files.